# ShareSheet Broadcast Receiver doesn't fire

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sharesheet

Trying to implement an Android share sheet, and following the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data). The sheet comes up and the sharing works as expected. However, the broadcast receiver never fires. Here is the code:

In the activity class:

```
// convenience method to create the sheet
var shareSheetIntent = shareSheetIntent(
    shareSheetTitleId = R.string.share_sheet_title,
    shareSheetImageId = R.drawable.ic_sheet_logo,
    messageToShare = messageText
)

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this,
    4321,
    Intent(this, MyShareSheetReceiver::class.java),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
).intentSender

shareSheetIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareSheetIntent, null, pendingIntent)

startActivity(shareSheetIntent)
```

And then this is my receiver:

```
class MyShareSheetReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        Log.d("hello", "share sheet receiver fired")
    }
}
```

Everything except the receiver works. The messages get sent to the intended recipient, but I don't see `onReceive` ever firing. What am I missing?

Edit:

Checking the logcat, I can see this message:

> Received BROADCAST intent 0x80a4d6 Key{broadcastIntent
> pkg=com.example.debug
> intent=cmp=com.example.debug/com.example.MyShareSheetReceiver
> flags=0x2000000 u=0} requestCode=4321 sent=0 from uid 1000

Comment: Do you see any system messages in Logcat suggesting that the OS cannot access your receiver?

Comment: Only one message. See my edit the the OP.

Comment: That's strange: the message makes it seem like your receiver worked. 

Comment: Yep. It certainly does. I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: This may sound weird, but reboot your test phone, or change `4321` to another value. Maybe there is something about your `PendingIntent` code that changed (and that `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` isn't accounting for) that is causing the problem. I've run into problems with the occasional "wedged" `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Never a bad idea to reboot. I also deleted the app, invalidate the caches and then re-ran it. Same result. I wondered if the context being supplied was being destroyed, so I logged out the various lifecycle methods. It hits `onStop` but not `onDestroy`, so I think the context survives. After I hit the back button to return to the app, it hits `onRestart` and `onResume` as I would expect.

Comment: Just for fun, I changed the context to use the application context but this changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer my own question because I believe that the Android docs are missing an incredibly important detail.

I solved this problem by adding the receiver class to the manifest. Nowhere in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data) of how to send data to other apps (and how to use a broadcast receiver to get a callback) does it mention having to add to the manifest.

Specifically, here is what I did:

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.example.MyShareSheetReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

In the general documentation on [BroadcastReceivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) there is discussion of using the context to register the receiver but this seems incompatible for a share sheet receiver due to the use of an IntentFilter, different flags, etc. Nonetheless, the share sheet receiver appears to be a context-registered receiver, which *should* make registering it in the manifest unnecessary.

So, for anyone else who may have this same issue, give this a try. Hopefully it will solve the problem for you. It did for me.